# не работает ng-show

Tags: angular

Коллеги, у меня вопрос - не могу понять почему не работает ng-show, в выражении мы получаем false и соотвественно должно не показываться. Или я что-то не так понимаю?

```
<span id="status__name" ng-show="this.getStatusName(task) !== 'Завершен'">${this.getStatusName(task)}</span>
```

Comment: Видимо, вы что-то делаете не так, по такому описанию воспроизвести [не удается](https://plnkr.co/edit/mJDD8IVIBCDZalHlx0rx?p=preview). Сделайте [mcve].